# Typesetting UTF8 listings with German Umlaute

Tags: listings, german

I'm having some issues with `listings` that include `German` Umlaute. The following example code generates a completely messed up PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX},inputencoding={utf8},extendedchars=false]
Staatsangehörigkeit
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[image: Umlaute]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

the normal listings package doesn't provide unicode support.
I use the following code to work around the Problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{listings}

\lstset{literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]
    Staatsangehörigkeit
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I also tried [listingsutf8](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8) and [listings2](http://www.atscire.de/index.php?nav=products/listings2) which ist BETA, but for me the literate solution just works perfekt ;)

edit:sry, marco has the same solution earlier...

Comment: This always shows the final Umlaut (in your case an *ö*) in the compiled PDF no matter which one was used in the source file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I can use `ÖÄÜßüäö~` with no problems.

Comment: I found my error. I had an additional *extendedchars* entry (the value beein true or false did not matter) in the lstset command, which caused the strange error I described.

Answer (score 12):

I use the following method in my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\lstset{literate={ö}{{\"o}}1}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX},inputencoding={utf8},extendedchars=false]
Staatsangehörigkeit
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Ulrike Fischer wrote in the [German community mrunix](http://mrunix.de/forums/showpost.php?p=306010&postcount=4):

> Weil listings eine Verbatim-Umgebung ist, die Befehle wie `\section`,
>   `\bfseries` und eben auch `\"a` nicht ausführt, sondern einfach ausdruckt.

English try:
Because `listings` is a verbatim environment, commands like `\section`, `\bfseries` and also `\"a` aren't executed, but instead just printed.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution to that provided by marco, perhaps a touch less typing, by using the key `escapeinside`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX},
             inputencoding={utf8}, extendedchars=false,  
             escapeinside=``]
Staatsangeh`ö`rigkeit
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

In general `utf8` and listings don't play well, especially if you importing files generated from different programs. The `backticks`, just enable whatever is enclosed between them to be escaped to LaTeX.