# UTF8 for listings

Tags: fonts, listings, unicode, listingsutf8

With German umlauts I have to define these characters ([Typesetting UTF8 listings with German Umlaute](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39640/typesetting-utf8-listings-with-german-umlaute)) and the following MWE is working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstdefinelanguage{rawtext}{}
\begin{document}
\lstset{extendedchars=true,language=rawtext,basicstyle=\ttfamily,literate=%
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1%
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1%
    {ä}{{\"a}}1%
    {ö}{{\"o}}1%
    {ü}{{\"u}}1%
    {ß}{{\ss}}1%
} 

\lstinputlisting{test.txt} 
\end{document}
```

With content of `test.txt` like:

```
ÄÖÜäöüß
abcd-1234
```

However, what can I do for real UTF8 support. I've created a directory with some international UTF8 filenames. They were displayed with a GUI

[image]

and also within a UTF8 compatible shell (bash):

```
logo.jpg
الجزيرة.نت.html
חדשות, ידיעות מהארץ והעולם - עיתון הארץ.html
Βικιπαίδεια.html
Администрация Президента Грузии.html
საქართველოს პრეზიდენტის ადმინისტრაცია.html
深圳航空有限责任公司 官网订票享受票价直减！.html
航空券 予約・空席照会・運賃案内・国内線｜ANA.html
```

But if the output of the `ls` command is in the file `test.txt`, the document can not be compiled, because I get errors like

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\lst@FillFixed@ not set up for use 
with LaTeX.
```

I'm looking for a rock solid solution to input generated files. As there is no definition, what kind of characters in the source file is used, all kind of UTF8 characters should be possible to use.

Comment: You can use packages like `minted` or `verbments`. Both packages uses Pygments to highlight code.

Comment: listings is an 8-bit package. So if you want to use it you will have to add long lists of literate-declarations (for pdflatex) or char lists (for lualatex/xelatex see eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396). Also you will need fonts for all the glyphs (which means imho that pdflatex isn't really an option). Without highlighting you could use xelatex/lualatex + verbatim together with some font which covers unicode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can you give a hint for such kind of universal font?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586503/complete-monospaced-unicode-font

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`listings` is an 8-bit package. So if you want to use it you will have to add long lists of literate-declarations (for pdflatex) or char lists (for lualatex/xelatex see eg [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396)). Also you will need fonts for all the glyphs (which means imho that pdflatex isn't really an option).

Without highlighting you could use xelatex/lualatex + the `verbatim` environment together with some font which covers unicode see e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938639/monospace-unicode-font  for such a font.

Comment: See also [Uniform Unicode for text, math and listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136195)