# verbments (listings alternative) and UTF-8

Tags: fonts, listings, unicode, verbments

This is a follow-up question to [UTF8 for listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110020/utf8-for-listings)

With these MWE I will not see the german umlauts in the resulted pdf (XeLaTeX was used):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbments}
\begin{document}
\begin{pyglist}[encoding=utf-8,language=text]
Test äöü Test
\end{pyglist}
\end{document}
```

What should I do to support UTF-8 in verbments?

Comment: It doesn't compile in my system.

Comment: I use Debian and I have to install `python-pygments` first. To compile, I use `xelatex -shell-escape inputtest.tex`

Comment: Since I cannot install that package in my machine, I found a solution to deal with UTF-8 and listings here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed (see the best answer).

Comment: well, this is not the answer to my question, because it's an follow-up question. `listings` in general has problems with UTF-8 but `verbments` was introduced to support unicode. Thanks for providing the link, too.

Comment: load the package `fontspec` which should be loaded by default of you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: As Marco Daniel observes, you *must* load `fontspec` for the thing to work.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: this was the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue isn't related to `verbments`. It's a font issue related to German umlauts. XeLaTeX uses utf-8 as default but the predefined font doesn't support this. A look in the log file shows for the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Test äöü Test
\end{document}
```

related part of the log-file:

```
Missing character: There is no ä in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ö in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr10!
```

To work with German umlauts you have to load the package `fontspec` which should be loaded normally. See: [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex)