# tcolorbox and Vietnamese

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox` with Exercise and Solution in Vietnamese, but I can't compile this code. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbset{texercisestyle/.style={arc=0.5mm, colframe=blue!25!yellow!90!white,
colback=blue!25!yellow!5!white, coltitle=blue!25!yellow!40!black,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!40!black}},
}}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside=exam]{baitap}[2][]{%
texercisestyle,
listing file={solutions/texercise\thetcbcounter.tex},
label={exe:#2},
record={\string\processsol{solutions/texercise\thetcbcounter.tex}{#2}},
title={Bài tập \thetcbcounter\hfill\textbf{Lời giải ở trang}  \pageref{sol:#2}},
list text={Exercise with solution on page \pageref{sol:#2}},#1}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Thử máy}
Thử máy
\tcbset{texercisestyle/.style={arc=0.5mm, colframe=blue!25!yellow!90!white,
colback=blue!25!yellow!5!white, coltitle=blue!25!yellow!40!black,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!40!black}},
}}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{baitap}{tabular_example}
Giải phương trình
\[(x^2 + 2x + 3) \cdot \sqrt{4x +5} + (6x^2 + 7x + 8) \cdot \sqrt{9x +10} = 9.\]
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
\begin{tcbwritetemp}
This is a solution.
\end{tcbwritetemp}
\end{tcboutputlisting}
\tcbuselistingtext%
\end{baitap}

\begin{baitap}{macro_twoparam}
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
Tôi không thể viết được tiếng Việt Nam (I can't write Vietnamese).
\end{tcboutputlisting}
\tcbuselistingtext%
This is a problem. \par\smallskip
\begin{tcbwritetemp}

\end{tcbwritetemp}
\tcbusetemplisting\par\smallskip\tcbusetemp%
\end{baitap}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcblistof[\subsection]{exam}{List of Exercises%
\label{listofexercises}}

\newtcbinputlisting{\processsol}[2]{%
texercisestyle,
listing only,
listing file={#1},
phantomlabel={sol:#2},%
title={Lời giải cho Bài tập \ref{exe:#2} ở trang \pageref{exe:#2}},
}
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @Hoang-NganNguyen Please see update.

Comment: Try with `\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the underlying `listings` package which gets problems when using `utf8` characters. You could use `\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}` to relax the problem a little bit, because this maps the characters to a selectable 8-bit encoding (`latin1` is the default). I do not know, if you can represent all Vietnamese characters in `latin1`, but I do not think so (it compiles, but the result is not good).

Another option would be to replace `listings` by `minted`. This allows using `utf8` characters. **Note that you may need to install additional software to use minted**.

[image]

This is produced by:

```
% !TeX encoding=UTF-8
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\tcbset{texercisestyle/.style={arc=0.5mm, colframe=blue!25!yellow!90!white,
colback=blue!25!yellow!5!white, coltitle=blue!25!yellow!40!black,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
%listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!40!black}},
minted options={fontsize=\small},
}}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside=exam]{baitap}[2][]{%
texercisestyle,
listing file={solutions/texercise\thetcbcounter.tex},
label={exe:#2},
record={\string\processsol{solutions/texercise\thetcbcounter.tex}{#2}},
title={Bài tập \thetcbcounter\hfill\textbf{Lời giải ở trang}  \pageref{sol:#2}},
list text={Exercise with solution on page \pageref{sol:#2}},#1}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Thử máy}
Thử máy
\tcbset{texercisestyle/.style={arc=0.5mm, colframe=blue!25!yellow!90!white,
colback=blue!25!yellow!5!white, coltitle=blue!25!yellow!40!black,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
%listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!40!black}},
minted options={fontsize=\small},
}}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{baitap}{tabular_example}
Giải phương trình
\[(x^2 + 2x + 3) \cdot \sqrt{4x +5} + (6x^2 + 7x + 8) \cdot \sqrt{9x +10} = 9.\]
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
\begin{tcbwritetemp}
This is a solution.
\end{tcbwritetemp}
\end{tcboutputlisting}
\tcbuselistingtext%
\end{baitap}

\begin{baitap}{macro_twoparam}
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
Tôi không thể viết được tiếng Việt Nam (I can't write Vietnamese).
\end{tcboutputlisting}
\tcbuselistingtext%
This is a problem. \par\smallskip
\begin{tcbwritetemp}

\end{tcbwritetemp}
\tcbusetemplisting\par\smallskip\tcbusetemp%
\end{baitap}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcblistof[\subsection]{exam}{List of Exercises%
\label{listofexercises}}

\newtcbinputlisting{\processsol}[2]{%
texercisestyle,
listing only,
listing file={#1},
phantomlabel={sol:#2},%
title={Lời giải cho Bài tập \ref{exe:#2} ở trang \pageref{exe:#2}},
}
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

There may be other ways to use `listings` after all. For German umlauts, one can use

```
\lstset{literate=%
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {ß}{{\ss}}1
}
```

A similar trick may work for Vietnamese characters too (?).

Comment: F.Sturm I copied your code. But I can not compile. I agree with you 'the result is not good'.

Comment: I hope, you add utf8 into your package.

Comment: @minthao_2011 The `listings` package would have to support `utf8`. On the other hand, `minted` does, but you need additional software for it, see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted.

Comment: @minthao_2011: My bad, after skimming through the `tcolorbox` manual, I knew that I misunderstood your problem. I deleted my *wrong answer*.

Comment: By the way, I followed Thomas' instruction and was able to compile your code. However, as pointed out by Thomas the font in listing does not look as good as the one in `bài tập`. To be able to compile this code, beside installing a bunch of additional LaTeX packages, I needed to install `pygmentize` on my Linux box ( for Windows you may try this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108661/how-to-use-minted-under-miktex-and-windows-7 ). After that I ran `pdflatex --shell-escape myfilename.tex`.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: A similar trick might be hard. For example, how can I create these characters `ể`, `ế`, `ữ`, `ệ`? These are missing character when using `listingsutf8`.

Comment: @minthao_2011: Since VnTeX uses vnr font by default, if you want your listing to use the same font, you can add `fontfamily=vnr` to `minted options`. This works for me.

Comment: @Hoang-NganNguyen The 'similar trick' is meant for adding 'literate' characters like the umlauts in my example. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110020/utf8-for-listings for more explanation. But I cannot say if this would be possible for Vietnamese characters  too.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thank you, I will look at that.

Answer (score 3):

Since VnTeX uses `vnr` font by default, if you want your listing to use the same font, you can add `fontfamily=vnr` to `minted options`. This works for me. 
[image]

```
% !TeX encoding=UTF-8
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\tcbset{texercisestyle/.style={arc=0.5mm, colframe=blue!25!yellow!90!white,
colback=blue!25!yellow!5!white, coltitle=blue!25!yellow!40!black,
fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
%listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!40!black}},
minted options={fontfamily=vnr,fontsize=\small},
}}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,list inside=exam]{baitap}[2][]{%
texercisestyle,
listing file={solutions/texercise\thetcbcounter.tex},
label={exe:#2},
record={\string\processsol{solutions/texercise\thetcbcounter.tex}{#2}},
title={Bài tập \thetcbcounter\hfill\textbf{Lời giải ở trang}  \pageref{sol:#2}},
list text={Exercise with solution on page \pageref{sol:#2}},#1}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section{Thử máy}
Thử máy

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{baitap}{tabular_example}
Giải phương trình
\[(x^2 + 2x + 3) \cdot \sqrt{4x +5} + (6x^2 + 7x + 8) \cdot \sqrt{9x +10} = 9.\]
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
\begin{tcbwritetemp}
This is a solution.
\end{tcbwritetemp}
\end{tcboutputlisting}
\tcbuselistingtext%
\end{baitap}

\begin{baitap}{macro_twoparam}
\begin{tcboutputlisting}
   Bây giờ tôi có thể viết được tiếng Việt Nam (Now, I can write Vietnamese).
\end{tcboutputlisting}
\tcbuselistingtext%
My previous problem is solved. \par\smallskip
\begin{tcbwritetemp}

\end{tcbwritetemp}
\tcbusetemplisting\par\smallskip\tcbusetemp%
\end{baitap}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcblistof[\subsection]{exam}{List of Exercises%
\label{listofexercises}}

\newtcbinputlisting{\processsol}[2]{%
texercisestyle,
listing only,
listing file={#1},
phantomlabel={sol:#2},%
title={Lời giải cho Bài tập \ref{exe:#2} ở trang \pageref{exe:#2}},
}
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

Comment: I could not get answers. Why?

Comment: If I remove two lines like you, I also got result like your picture. My problem is how to get answer?

Comment: @minthao_2011: I updated my answer by adding `fontfamily=vnr` to `minted options`.

Comment: I down know compile pdflatex --shell-escape in Texmaker. Can you help me?

Comment: @minthao_2011: Is this the software you use, http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/ ? If yes, then go to `Configure Texmaker`, choose `pdflatex + viewPDF`, and in the box below, replace the content by `pdflatex --shell-escape %.tex`. I guess that's the way you change the compilation commmand.

Comment: Is this the line pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex?

Comment: I miss pygmentize. How can I input?

Comment: Yes, that is the line. I don't understand your question about `pygmentize`. But you just need to install it, you don't need to do anything else. Ah, make sure you have python install.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41937/discussion-between-minthao-2011-and-hoang-ngan-nguyen).