# Package inputenc Error

Tags: input-encodings

I use a package to right Latex code on Latex, but when I used special caracters I got this error

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ...

this is a sample of code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
      {
      language=[LaTeX]TeX,
      breaklines=true,
      basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
      keywordstyle=\color{blue},
      identifierstyle=\color{black},
      }
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    Ceci est un nom composé en fin de ligne du mathématicien Albert~EINSTEIN.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

like you see, the phrase on the listing bloc contain special caracters, I tried utf8x instead of utf8, it doesn't work, so how can I solve this, please ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110020/utf8-for-listings

Comment: the link in this question is not found, that's why I asked

Comment: Replacing ‘mathématicien’ with ‘physicien’ will solve part of the problem :-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listings doesn't work with `utf8`. Add this option to `\lstset`:

```
  literate={é}{{\'e}}1
```

and similarly for other non-ascii characters (separate all such specifications with space).

Comment: it works for é, but how can I found the others symbols like è, ê ...

Comment: Add the prehistoric code for accented letters: `{è}{{\`e}}1 {ê}{{\ˆe}}1 {à}{{\`a}}1 `, &c (don't forget accented capital letters).