# How to write Swedish letters in code listing (lstlisting) in Latext?

Tags: listings, scandinavian-letters

I am writing R codes in lstlisting:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{ForestGreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\lstset{language=R,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
breaklines=true,
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
   studentsNames = c("Björn","Hökan")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But, the latex returns an error and it cannot show the Swedish letters (ö, å, ä) in lstlisting.
Is there any solution?

Comment: When I run your code, I get:" Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `ForestGreen'". When I remove the colour, the umlaute are printed fine.

Comment: Ok right I have to add \definecolor{ForestGreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0} to the code

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39645/1090

Answer (score 1):

You can define some UTF-8 characters (encoded by two or more bytes) via the `literate` keyword.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{ForestGreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\lstset{language=R,
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
otherkeywords={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
morekeywords={TRUE,FALSE},
deletekeywords={data,frame,length,as,character},
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
breaklines=true,
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}

\lstset{
  literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\texteuro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
  {«}{{<<}}1 {»}{{>>}}1
  {°}{{\up{o}}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
   studentsNames = c("Björn","Hökan")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code with XeLaTeX, it was fine, but in pdfLaTeX I got:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
```

The difference is that pdfLaTeX doesn't really understand UTF-8 and because `lstlisting` is parsing the input one character at a time, this is one of the places where the difference matters. The Unicode engines, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX understand that `0xC3 0xB6` is a single character, but pdfLaTeX will happily split it up and then get upset about the results.